# Refreshing the page in javascript sometimes results in NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript/jquery task which runs on page load.

Nothing changes on the page when I click refresh - I'm just giving it some reasonable testing - however I noticed that sometimes one of the functions doesn't complete correctly.

Here are the functions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initialise();
    load();
});

// 1. Cache the main selectors just in case the window is resized
function initialise() {
    $banners = $("#header .banner");
}

// 2. Loop through each of the elements
function load() {
    $banners.each(function () {
        setBannerStyle($(this));
    });
}

// 3. Add attributes to each of the banner elements
function setBannerStyle($selector) {

    icon = $selector.find(".icon").first().length;
    rows = getRows($selector.find(".message").first());

    $selector.attr({
        "data-icon": icon,
        "data-rows": rows
    });
}

// 4. Helper to do the workings out
function getRows($selector) {

    var height = $selector.height();
    var lineHeight = parseFloat($selector.css("line-height"));
    var rows = Math.round(height / lineHeight);

    return rows > 2 ? 2 : rows;
}
```

As you can see there is no complexity and the number of elements to loop through is rarely more than one.

However, on rare occasions the number of rows returns NAN. How can I ensure that a valid number is always returns (or at least improve the chance of it not happening). It currently fails about once in 10 on my quad core i5 processor.

To be clear, I don't wan't to set defaults when it fails - I want to try and stop it failing in the first place.

Any advice appreciated as I'm not too great with javascript.

Comment: when `getRows()` is called -- has the DOM successfully loaded #header .banner .message ? (my guess is that the DOM element didn't render in time for when the JS executed)

Comment: If you are getting NAN for number of rows that means either height or lineHeight in null.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: @git-e-up - from what I can see, document ready waits for html - and the thing that I'm measuring is values inside html elements - so should be okay.

Comment: @doug - I thought document ready was to ensure the html was ready.

Comment: @JohnOhara I'm not an expert, but I think that while the DOM may be loaded, not all images necessarily have. So if you're trying to get the height of a banner, it may not be available at the time of `$(document).ready`

Comment: @git-e-up - the container only contains text.

Comment: @RajeshKumar - it is indeed line-height but I need to know how I can make it more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code which seems to work a treat - replaced document.ready() and hammered it hundreds of times a minutes without fail.

```
let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    clearInterval(stateCheck);
    // document ready
  }
}, 100);
```

Credit goes to : [this site](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/detect-document-ready-in-pure-js/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.outerHeight()` instead of `.height()` when getting `var height`

Also, ensure that the `line-height` variable is set on the `$selector` element before attempting to parse it, and the `$selector` variable is also not undefined.

If any of those variables aren't set for any reason, you'll get a NaN result.

You can `console.log(variable)` all of these to find out what's going on and see the variable states when something doesn't work.

This sounds like it could be a race condition, so if the above suggestions don't work, try using `setTimeout(function, interval)` to delay the execution of those functions.